# Convexity of coherent information - erroneous argument!

Tags: entropy, information-theory

Consider a state $\rho_{AB}$. Let it have purification $\psi_{A'AB}$. I am interested in the coherent information of this state which is given by

$$I(A\rangle B)_\rho = S(B)_\rho - S(AB)_\rho$$

I can rewrite this as follows using the fact that $\psi_{A'AB}$ is pure. 
\begin{align}
I(A\rangle B) &= S(B)_\rho - S(AB)_\rho\\
&=S(A'A)_\psi - S(A')_\psi \\
&= S(A|A')_\psi
\end{align}

Now let us consider $J(A\rangle B) = -I(A\rangle B)$. We have
\begin{align}
J(A\rangle B) &= S(AB)_\rho - S(B)_\rho\\
&= S(A|B)_\psi
\end{align}

But the quantum conditional entropy $S(X|Y)$ is a concave function of the input state (see Corollary 11.13 in Nielsen and Chuang). So both $J$ and $I$ are concave. This would imply that the coherent information is a linear function of $\psi_{A'AB}$ which I believe is not true. Where did I make a mistake in the argument?

Comment: While $S(A|A')_\psi$ is indeed concave with respect to $\psi$, it is *not* concave with respect to $\rho$.

Comment: In particular, suppose $\psi_0$ and $\psi_1$ are purifications of $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$ respectively, and consider the state $\rho= p\rho_0+(1-p)\rho_1$ for some $p\in(0,1)$. Taking a convex mixture of the purifications $\psi_0$ and $\psi_1$ will not yield a purification for $\rho$. So we can't really say anything about the value $I(A\rangle B)_{p\rho_0+(1-p)\rho_1}$ since we can't say much about what the purification of $p\rho_0+(1-p)\rho_1$ will be in terms of the purifications of $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$.